# How to bring debug library "python37_d.lib" to Anaconda?

Tags: python, windows, debugging, anaconda, pytorch

I [try to build pytorch from source on Windows](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch#from-source). It failed with fatal error LNK1104 "can't open python37_d.lib".

Then I installed python3.7 from www.python.org and select "Download debug binaries". Then I copied the whole newly installed python folder to Anaconda3\envs\MyEnv and replace existing old files. When I built pytorch again, it shows LNK1104 with "can't open python37.lib". I checked and made sure both "python37_d.lib" and "python37.lib" are under Anaconda3\envs\MyEnv\libs.

Is my method correct(to use self-installed python files to replace the ones under Anaconda)? Is there any package from which I can install the python37_d.lib by executing "conda install "?

Comment: that may be interesting: https://github.com/conda-forge/python-feedstock/issues/73